# Python - identify mechanical systems from input / output in the time domain

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, power-spectral-density

I have a set of input / output time series measurements for different times and machines.

- I assume each machine behavior doesn't change over time
- output is generally linked to the integral of input
- Machines have different characteristic that would allow me to discern them
- I generally work with Python

My first approach is building FFT(Y)/FFT(X) to observe response at different frequencies. Then the idea is to compare FFT(Y)/FFT(X) graphs to see if I can observe differents machines.

Is the approach correct (notably regarding the part where I expect the output being an integration of the input) ? Are there better ways to proceed ?

Comment: When you say "identify" do you mean that in the sense of "system identification", i.e., trying to determine the system characteristics from the input/output data?  Or do you mean in the sense of an inventory, where you're saying "oh, yes, that's an Owens BR549, not a Dufensmirtz AC46".

Comment: I don't really want to get the specific mechanical caracteristic of the machines. I mostly want to see If machines behave similarly / or if there are outliers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the machines are LTI (Linear Time Invariant) systems, they are completely determined by their transfer function. In theory $FFT(y)/FFT(x)$ will give you this but that's not that easy in practice.

You need enough good enough signal to noise ratio at ALL frequencies. If the input has low or no energy at some frequencies you'll end up with a "divide by zero" problem. It also requires proper framing since the output typically lags the input by a frequency dependent amount.

You may be better off determining the impulse response using an adaptive filter and then doing the Fourier Transform of that.

Once you have the transfer function of the system you can try to identify the poles and the zeros of the transfer function (which isn't a trivial problem). These corresponds to masses, springs, resonances, resistances, modes,  etc of your machines.